# Gravatar shows hash instead of picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, navbar, gravatar

i want to use gravatar to show pictures on my platform, but instead of doing so i only see the MD5 hash.

Here is my code of "application_helper.rb"

```
def avatar_url(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email).downcase
    "https//www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.jpg?d=identical&s=150"
  end
end
```

I also tried `d=mm`and `d=identicon`, which also did not work.

Here is the code im using in the navbar:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <%= image_tag avatar_url(current_user), class: "img-circle" %>&nbsp;
                  <%= current_user.fullname %> <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

[Picture of the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYpeC.png)

Anything i could try?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gravatar URL is wrong, you're missing the `:` after `https`. Also the `www` is not necessary.

```rb
def avatar_url(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    "https://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.jpg?d=identical&s=150"
  end
end
```

https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/ruby/

Comment: The second line should read `gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)` https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/ruby/

Comment: Good point @max, fixed! Although the root cause of the problem was caused by the wrong URL and not the normalization of the email address. Also added the docs link to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but any email with uppercase characters would have created an invalid hash as well. `Digest::MD5.hexdigest('Foo@bar.com').downcase != Digest::MD5.hexdigest('Foo@bar.com'.downcase)`.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBruckmayer works fine. I checked the code 500 times and did not see that the ```:``` are missing....

Comment: Yes Max, that's why I acknowledged it and even changed it in the answer. However, the root problem was the wrong URL and not upcase vs downcase. In case the hash is wrong, the default gravatar image is shown but in the problem at hand no image was shown at all because of the wrong URL. Although your comment was correct it is not the solution to the question.